# Can a percentage be estimated as reliably with a small group?

Tags: estimation

I realise that my question is quite simplistic for this site but I will ask anyway.     I am wondering if percentage results become more unreliable the smaller the group is (I am not referring to a sample of the group rather questioning the whole group). If yes, is there a way to determine that?

For example 5% of the 30 people that received a direct-sales call hang up the phone. Does that mean that 5% of 8 people called would be expected to hang up? Or is the percentage unreliable the smaller the number which is my main question?

I hope that this was clear enough.   Thank you very much

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. What is your reasoning to get from 5% of your large group hanging up to expecting 30% of a smaller group to hang up?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. BIG MISTAKE I was intending to wright 5%  again.

Comment: no worries. So if I've understood your question right, what you're asking is essentially as follows. Consider a population in which a proportion $p$ have a certain characteristic. When you take a sample from the population how does the uncertainty around the proportion that you estimate from the sample, i.e. $\hat{p} = \dfrac{\textrm{number measured with characteristic}}{n}$,  change with the size $n$ of the sample? Did I understand you right?

Comment: Are the 8 different people than the 30, or are the 8 part of the 30? Is it the smallness of the 30 or the smallness of the 8 that's of concern?

Answer (score 1):

The sample proportion $\hat{p}$ is an unbiased estimator to the population proportion $p$, regardless of $n$. Therefore, if 5% hanged-up in one sample, and you no other information or prior beliefs, your best bet regarding the proportion of people that will hang-up, both in general and in any other sample is also 5%.

Your suspicion that the reliability of $\hat{p}$ is reduced for small $p$ is of course correct. Consider the case of a sample of a single person! You can build a [Binomial confidence interval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval) around $\hat{p}$ - it's determined only by the number of 'successes' and the number of total events ($n$). This confidence interval will reflect the uncertainty caused by the finite size of the sample - the smaller $n$ is, the larger the interval will become.

If the population proportion $p$ is known (you know that in general, 5% hang-up) and you want to know what is the probability to observe a particular $\hat{p}$ for a sample with a particular size ($n$), you can look at the [Binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) defined by $p$ and $n$. This could tell you what is the probability that 1/8 will hang up, 2/8 will hang up, etc.